# Вывод результата запроса без текста запроса через SQLDeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

Следующий скрипты выполняется через Oracle SQLDeveloper.

```
set termout off
set echo off
set heading off
set feed off
set pagesize 10000
spool 'e:\1.txt'
select * from myDB;
spool off
quit
```

Вроде по документалке должен быть только вывод результата без вывода текста запроса.

Однако при выводе в верху файла остается текст `> select * from myDB`

Как избавиться от этой строки?

Comment: У меня отрабатывает нормально (без текста запроса). Убедитесь еще раз что проверяете верный файл (удалить файл вывода и запустить скрипт), и нет ошибок при выполнении.

Comment: удалил файл и запустил скрипт. появляется снова файл с той же строкой. ошибок при выполнении нету.

Comment: Как запускаете скрипт? Через SQL*Plus? Если нет, то попробуйте через него.

Comment: да не через него, большое спасибо.

Comment: Утверждение, что ошибок нет не совсем верно. Вы выключили все сообщения начиная с `termout off`. Попробуйте передвинуть его вниз или временно отключить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположу, что проблема связана со средой в которой выполняется скрипт.

Например, SQLDeveloper при запуске скрипта пытается эмулировать поведение sqlplus при покомандном выполнении, из-за этого текст запроса может попасть в вывод несмотря на `set echo off`.

Варианты решения проблемы:

- вынести скрипт в файл и запускать его как файл:

  ```
  @script.sql;
  ```

либо вынести в отдельный файл сам запрос:

```
...пропущены строки
spool 'e:\1.txt'
@script.sql;
spool off
quit
```

- запускать скрипт через sqlplus.

  ```
   sqlplus user/password@db;
   @script.sql;
  ```

Более подробно в похожем вопросе на английском: [Spool Command: Do not output SQL statement to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033943/spool-command-do-not-output-sql-statement-to-file).

Comment: да я запускал в SQLDeveloper и после запуска через скрипт проблема прошла.

Comment: @Padawan отлично! Внес сведения в вопрос.